# Need to check if an answer in a quiz is correct (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with legislators and the parties they belong to. Five questions are outputted with random names and parties and the input is either Y or N. I need to now figure out how to check if its true or not but I am stumped. 
The code:

```
from random import *

legislators = { "Tsang Yok-sing" : "DAB", "Albert Ho" :
"Democratic", "Lee Cheuk-yan" : "Labour", "James To" :
"Democratic", "Chan Kam-lam" : "DAB", "Lau Wong-fat" :
"Economic Synergy", "Emily Lau" : "Democratic" }

names = list(legislators.keys())
parties = list(legislators.values())

numberCorrect = 0

for i in range(0, 5):
    name = names[randrange(len(names))]
    party = parties[randrange(len(parties))]
    ans = input("Does "+name+" belong to "+party+" (Y/N)?\n")
```

Just need to get any advice on where to start on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You already know the expected answer by checking legislators['name'] == party. Now you validate user's condition with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import *

legislators = { "Tsang Yok-sing" : "DAB", "Albert Ho" :
"Democratic", "Lee Cheuk-yan" : "Labour", "James To" :
"Democratic", "Chan Kam-lam" : "DAB", "Lau Wong-fat" :
"Economic Synergy", "Emily Lau" : "Democratic" }

names = list(legislators.keys())

parties = list(legislators.values())

numberCorrect = 0

for i in range(0, 5):

    name = names[randrange(len(names))]

    party = parties[randrange(len(parties))]

    ans = raw_input("Does "+name+" belong to "+party+ " Y/N?")

    if ans == 'Y':

        if legislators[name] == party:

            print 'correct'

        else:
            print 'error'

    elif ans == 'N':

        if legislators[name] == party:

            print 'error'
        else:

            print 'correct'
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem with your program:

Picking a random member and a random party gives a 34/49 or approximately 70% chance of the party being wrong, so always answering 'n'  will give an average score of 3.47 / 5 correct.

We can fix this like so:

```
# 50% chance of using the correct party,
# 50% chance of using any other party
test_party = party if random() < 0.5 else choice(other_parties[party])
```

I have also:

- created a function `get_yn()` which accepts a variety of yes and no values and returns `True` for yes and `False` for no
- used `random.choice` to pick a member instead of indexing with `random.randrange`
- moved the per-question code into a `do_question()` function which returns `True` for a correct answer and `False` for a wrong one
- added user feedback on the result of each question

The result:

```
from random import choice, random

NUM_QUESTIONS = 5

def get_yn(prompt, error_message=None, yes_values={'', 'y', 'yes'}, no_values={'n', 'no'}):
    """
    Prompt repeatedly for user input until a yes_value or no_value is entered
    """
    while True:
        result = input(prompt).strip().lower()
        if result in yes_values:
            return True
        elif result in no_values:
            return False
        elif error_message is not None:
            print(error_message)

# reference list of legislators            
member_party = {
    "Tsang Yok-sing": "DAB",
    "Albert Ho":      "Democratic",
    "Lee Cheuk-yan":  "Labour",
    "James To":       "Democratic",
    "Chan Kam-lam":   "DAB",
    "Lau Wong-fat":   "Economic Synergy",
    "Emily Lau":      "Democratic"
}

members = list(member_party.keys())
parties = list(member_party.values())
# For each party, we keep a list of all parties except itself
#   (this is used to balance questions so each question
#   has a 50% chance of being correct)
other_parties = {party:[p for p in parties if p != party] for party in parties}

def do_question():
    # pick a member at random
    member = choice(members)
    party = member_party[member]
    test_party = party if random() < 0.5 else choice(other_parties[party])
    # question user
    prompt = "Does {} belong to the {} party? [Y/n] ".format(member, test_party)
    answer = get_yn(prompt)
    # score answer
    if answer:
        if party == test_party:
            print("You are right!")
            return True
        else:
            print("Sorry, {} is from the {} party.".format(member, party))
            return False
    else:
        if party == test_party:
            print("Sorry, {} actually is from the {} party!".format(member, party))
            return False
        else:
            print("You are right! {} is from the {} party.".format(member, party))
            return True

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Whose Party Is This quiz:")
    correct = sum(do_question() for _ in range(NUM_QUESTIONS))
    print("You got {}/5 correct!".format(correct))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough for the effort you have put in to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the originals stored in a dict, you can just check if `legislators[name] == party`.

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thank you

Comment: Not quite.  If the user typed `n` then checking if `legislators[name]` is equal to `party` will get the opposite answer from what he wants.

Comment: Do you mean "N" or "n". You already have the answer pre-defined. Just compare against that. It seems correct.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to python so I don't know much yet

Answer (score 0):

Adding a code example. You code is hardcoded to upper case Y/N.

Just before the `input` compute the validity of your random combination.

```
if legislators[name] == party:
    valid = "Y"
else:
    valid = "N"
```

Now after the `input` you need to do this:

```
if ans==valid:
   if valid == 'N':
      print "Yes, the member does not belong to that party."
   else:
      print "Yes, the member belongs to that party."
else:
    print "Sorry, your answer is wrong."
```